# Postdocs or RTDa/b positions and a question on PhD acquired outside of Italy and equivalence with the Italian title

Tags: phd, mathematics, job-search, early-career, italy

Is it necessary to have obtained the "equivalence" of Ph.D. acquired in another country (Germany in my case) to the Italian title *before* applying for postdocs or RTDa/b positions in Italy?

I found [this page](http://www.miur.it/0002Univer/0021Offert/0095Dottor/0114Docume/6373Docume_cf2.htm) about the process. Are there more detailed resources to guide me through the administrative process of requesting the equivalence? Is there anything in particular that I should be careful about?

Comment: I think it would be possible to clarify this with prospective guides in Italy?